# Hide a block on losing focus

Tags: jquery, lost-focus

I have a sub-menu. I want to hide it when user clicks anywhere outside it. I try focusout() and blur() jQuery methods, but they don't work.

Comment: show what you have maybe jfiddle you can also use just pure hide()

Answer (score 1):

```
// listen click event on document   
$(document).click(function(e){
    // if the event is not triggered by your submenu, hide it.
    if(e.target.id != id_of_sub_menu){
        $("#id_of_sub_menu").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

// here is div whose id is 'block'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#block').mouseout(function() {
       $(this).hide();
    })
});
```

Hope it helps!!